# Avoid gnu make automatic file deletion

Tags: makefile

GNU make is deleting my object files automatically. I don't understand why...
My goal is small test programs generation, hence each source file is an independent program which uses no other module.

My makefile is:

```
# This makefile is written for Windows cmd shell
SHELL=C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe

# FILES
SRCS=$(wildcard src/*.cpp)
BINS=$(patsubst %.cpp,bin/%.exe,$(notdir $(SRCS)))

all:compile

obj/%.o:src/%.cpp
    g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++11 -m64 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0400 -c -o $@ $<

bin/%.exe:obj/%.o
    g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++11 -m64 $^ -o $@

clean:
    if exist obj\*.o del /Q obj\*.o

mrproper:clean
    if exist bin\*.exe del /Q bin\*.exe

compile:$(BINS)

rebuild:clean all

.PHONY:all compile clean mrproper rebuild
```

Running GNU make with, for instance, a single source file does as follows:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++11 -m64 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0400 -c -o obj/Tester.o src/Tester.cpp
g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++11 -m64 obj/Tester.o -o bin/Tester.exe
rm obj/Tester.o
```

Why is my object file deleted?
How to avoid it?

If I replace either `obj/%.o:src/%.cpp` by `obj/Tester.o:src/Tester.cpp` or `bin/%.exe:obj/%.o` by `bin/Tester.exe:obj/Tester.o` the file Tester.o is not deleted, but this is not what I need.

Comment: How do you run the `make` command ? Because there's no `rm` in the file you provide, so it must come from somewhere else...

Comment: @Zelnes with no arguments, from a Windows cmd console (not a powershell one). I don't know where this unix shell command comes from...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the links yihsiui provides, I come with another answer to my own question.
The object files are deleted because they don't exist and the rules I wrote made them intermediate. To avoid them to be flagged as intermediate, they must be an explicit target in some rule. I still need the pattern rule to generate the object file because I use the pattern substitution to compute the name of the object file. So, why not simply add an "empty" rule?

```
OBJS=$(patsubst %.cpp,obj/%.o,$(notdir $(SRCS)))
```

(...)

```
$(OBJS):
```

Comment: This is the right solution for dealing with intermediate files.  Normally this type of thing is not needed because normally an executable needs to link more than one object file, so you have to list all the object files as prerequisites of the executable, which makes them non-intermediate.  Only in this unique situation where you want to compile a single object file into an executable will you run into this situation.

Answer (score 5):

Since you use implicit rule (such as ‘%.o’), object file will be delete after make.

Add special target `.PRECIOUS` to protect it.

```
.PRECIOUS: obj/%.o
```

Reference:

[Special Built-in Target Names](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html)

[Chains of Implicit Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html#Chained-Rules)

Comment: I don't think `obj/%.o:src/%.cpp` is an implicit rule. Looks like a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html#Pattern-Rules), so `.PRECIOUS` shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: This works, but why after deleting object files calling make does not rebuild anything?

Comment: Using `.PRECIOUS` to preserve intermediate files is not a good idea.  This can cause problems: for example if make is killed (which will cause the compiler to be killed) and the object file is left half-written and corrupted, make won't clean it up for you because it's `.PRECIOUS`.  That's not what `.PRECIOUS` is designed to do and there are much better ways to avoid intermediate files.  IMO this should not be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: _Implicit rule_ covers both suffix rules and pattern rules: both are considered "implicit" because neither one lists an explicit target.